# PDO fetchall cannot fetch all data

Tags: php, pdo

If I set limit 14205 PDO:fetchALl returns rows, no problem. But
with limit more than 1405 or without setting limit  PDO:fetchAll cannot retrieve rows at all.

Comment: Does it throw an error? Without limit and with more than `1405` (or `14205`?) could cause the same issue; maybe maxing out the memory or hitting time limit.

Comment: fetchAll() can be extremely memory inefficient for large data sets. See here http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#104609

Comment: No it is not error it is limit by system or php but I dont know where is this directive in php.ini

Comment: That is it I solved this problem by setting memory_limit=-1 in php.ini